# include playbook with a variable name, which is defined on another host

Tags: ansible

I have some trouble getting my playbook to include another. I use a playbook to roll out a clean VM. After that, I'd like to run another playbook, to configure the VM in a certain way. I've added the new host to the inventory and have ssh access to it.

Our team has set up a project per servertype. I've retrieved the right path to the project in an early stage (running against localhost) and used set_fact to put it in "servertype_project".
I expect this to work (at the playbook-level, running against the new VM):

```
- name: "Run servertype playbook ({{ project }}) on VM"
vars:
  project: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['servertype_project'] }}"
include: "{{ project }}/ansible/playbook.yml"
```

But it fails the syntax check with this message:

> ERROR! {{ hostvars['localhost']['servertype_project'] }}: 'hostvars' is undefined

I can retrieve the right string if I refer to {{ hostvars['localhost']['servertype_project'] }} from within a task, but not from the level in which I can include another playbook.

Since the value is determined at runtime, I think set_fact is the correct way to store the variable, but that one is host-specific. Is there any way I can pass it along to this host as well? Or did I miss some global-var-like-option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not missing anything. This is expected. Facts are bound to hosts and `hostvars` is not accessible in playbook scope.

There is no way to define a variable that would be accessible in the `include` declaration, except for passing it as an `extra-vars` argument in CLI. But if you use an in-memory inventory (which is a reasonable assumption), then calling another `ansible-playbook` instance is out of question.

I think you should rethink your flow and instead of including a dynamically-defined play, have statically-defined play(s) running against your in-memory inventory and include the roles conditionally.